# UILocalNotification marked as ambiguous in Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

What am I missing?

```
var notifications = [Int, UILocalNotification]()
```

Why does this give me the error:

```
"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
```

Comment: vote to close since the issue was a wrong character. Is SO really a syntax checker for cases like this?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Well the error is misleading, when I read it I think about scope error for UILocalNotification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a dictionary then your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
var notifications = [Int : UILocalNotification]()
```

Comment: Thanks, also I read that's because the way I did it instantiate a NSDictionary instead? `  var notifications: Dictionary<Int, UILocalNotification> = [:]` valid too?

Comment: yes, that is effectively the same thing, also `var notifications: [Int : UILocalNotification] = [:]`